# PyInstaller converted EXE stopped to work on Python 3.6 64-bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I encountered an error message that said the `pyinstaller` converted `.exe` has stopped to work. So I wrote a testing code to verify if there is any problem with the python libraries I used works or not.

Here is the testing code that works after converted to `.exe`.

```
import random
import pygame

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
pygame.init()
while 1 == 1:
    print(random.randint(1, 2))
```

And here is the code that doesn't work after converted to `.exe`.

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import os.path

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)

stop = False

bokmål = ['slett','av den','trev','svingte','sank','synest','slikke','nytter','slipp','frem','steder','enten','besøke','plukket','satt','deres','jobbe','husk']
nynorsk = ['sleit','av han','treiv','svinga','sokk','synest','sleike','nyttar','slepp','fram','stadar','anten','besøke','plukke','sett','dokkar','jobbe','hugs']

wrong_numbers = 0
random_number = random.randint(0, len(bokmål))
right_numbers = 0

words_typed_wrong = []
menu = False
answer = ''
answer_done = False

button_pressed = ''
filplasering = ''
change_filplasering = False
menu_out = False
navn_på_dock = ''
change_navn_på_dock = False
shift = False

def message_to_screen (melding, farge, x, y):
    screen_text = font.render (melding, True, farge)
    gameDisplay.blit (screen_text, (x, y))

def text_opperating (text, knapp, pos, change):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouse_x, mouse_y = mouse_pos
    mouse_left, f, g = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    x, y = pos

    if (mouse_x < x + 200 and mouse_x > x) and (mouse_y > y and mouse_y < y + 22):
        mouse_text = True
        if mouse_left == 1:
            change = True    
    else:
        mouse_text = False

    if change == True:
        if knapp == 'backspace':
            text = text[:-1]
        elif knapp == 'return':
            change = False
        else:
            text += knapp

    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255, 255, 255), (x - 2, y - 2, 200, 22), 1)
    gameDisplay.blit(font.render(text, True, (255,255,255)), (x, y))
    return ((text, change))

while not stop:
    gameDisplay.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            stop = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                button_pressed = 'backspace'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                menu = True
                button_pressed = 'escape'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT:
                shift = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                button_pressed = ' '
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                button_pressed = 'return'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SEMICOLON:
                button_pressed = 'ø'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFTBRACKET:
                button_pressed = 'å'
            elif event.key == pygame.K_QUOTE:
                button_pressed = 'æ'
            else:
                button_pressed = pygame.key.name(event.key)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT or event.key == pygame.K_RSHIFT:
                shift = False

    if shift == True:
        if button_pressed == '.':
            button_pressed = ':'

        button_pressed = button_pressed.upper()

    elif button_pressed == '=':
        button_pressed = '\\'

    if menu == True:

        if menu_out == True and button_pressed == 'escape':
            menu = False
            change_filplasering = False
            change_navn_på_dock = False
        menu_out = True

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (100, 100, 200), (150, 150, 200, 50))
        gameDisplay.blit(font.render('lagre dokument', True, (255, 255, 255)), (170, 165))

        message_to_screen(('Antall ord: ' + str(len(bokmål))),(255, 255, 255), 20, 20)
        message_to_screen('filplasering: ',(255, 255, 255), 20, 50)
        message_to_screen('navn:', (255, 255, 255), 20, 80)
        filplasering, change_filplasering = text_opperating(filplasering, button_pressed, (150, 50), change_filplasering)
        navn_på_dock, change_navn_på_dock = text_opperating(navn_på_dock, button_pressed, (150, 80), change_navn_på_dock)
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_left, gh, fd = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if mouse_x > 150 and mouse_x < 350 and mouse_y > 150 and mouse_y < 200 and mouse_left == True:
            complet_file = os.path.join(filplasering, navn_på_dock + ".txt")
            file = open(complet_file, "w")
            file.write(str(words_typed_wrong))
            file.close()    
    else:
        if button_pressed == 'return':
            answer_done = True
        elif button_pressed == 'backspace':
            answer = answer [:-1]
        else:
            answer += button_pressed

        menu_out = False
        if answer_done == True:
            answer_done = False
            if answer == nynorsk[random_number]:
                right_numbers += 1
                gameDisplay.fill((0, 0, 0))
                pygame.draw.polygon(gameDisplay, (0, 255, 0), ((150, 200), (90, 140), (110, 120), (150, 160), (280, 50), (300, 70)))
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(1)
                random_number = random.randint(0, len(bokmål) - 1)

            else:
                wrong_numbers += 1
                gameDisplay.fill((255, 0, 0))
                text = 'feil svar, riktig svar er: ' + nynorsk[random_number]
                gameDisplay.blit(font.render(text, True, (255, 255, 255)), (25, 100))
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(2)
                words_typed_wrong.append(nynorsk[random_number])
            answer = ''

        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255, 255, 255), (100, 300, 200, 50), 5)
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255, 255, 255), (100, 100, 200, 50), 5)

        gameDisplay.blit (font.render (('feil ord: ' + str(wrong_numbers)), True, (255, 255, 255)), (25, 10))
        gameDisplay.blit (font.render (('riktige ord: ' + str(right_numbers)), True, (255, 255, 255)), (150, 10))

        gameDisplay.blit (font.render (bokmål[random_number], True, (255, 255, 255)), (110, 110))
        gameDisplay.blit (font.render (answer, True, (255, 255, 255)), (110, 310))

    if random_number == len(bokmål) - 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 20, 20))

    button_pressed = ''
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. I didn't find out what that went wrong, but I tried cx_freeze and than it worked. I don't know what went wrong but if you se this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSoOwSqTSrs
and use the code from the cx_freeze description:
http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html
would you probably get it to work.